# why pd.to_numeric won't give me an error alert?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm sorry I can't show you the data frame because I have not yet figured out how to do that. Basically, I was trying to convert one column of my data to numbers. I wrote like this:

```
df['column1'] = pd.to_numeric(  df['column1'], errors='raise' )
```

Then nothing happened. No alert, no errors, and the dtype is still 'object'. After a closer look, I found out that there were actually several missing values in that column, and they were shown as '.............................'. So I simply modified my code a little bit:

```
df['column1'] = pd.to_numeric(  df['column1'], errors='coerce' )
```

and the problem is solved.

What I don't understand is, why there was no error alert at the first time. 
I figured it might have something to do with those dots. I can't even use print() function on them.

Comment: Did you really have 'arise' instead of 'raise'?

Comment: @JonClements lol sorry, a typo. Let me change it.

Comment: Share the dataframe before you do the conversion maybe?? We need data! :)

Comment: @AntonvBR  I'm trying to figure out how to do that. Any suggestion?

Comment: `print(df.head().to_dict())` or `print(df['column1'].to_dict())`

Comment: @AntonvBR This is the tricky part. Those dots won't even allow me to print them out.

Comment: @AntonvBR No. It's almost like this values have some kind of immunity that makes functions fail. I can print out the whole dataframe though. Those values are shown as '..........................................'

Comment: Try to figure it out, hard to help if not